# Render template and JSON in Pyramid

Tags: python, json, pyramid

I'm using distal to load JSON values from the session into a web application.  However when I initially render the page using a Chameleon template, I would like to load some arbitrary JSON values to fill out the structure.  What is the best way to do this?

What I'm doing currently is to render the page with the template, and then use javascript to request the JSON when the document is ready.  However, this causes a stutter in the loading.

Comment: what have you left out of your question that is preventing you from just returning extra values from your view to the renderer??

Comment: The JavaScript call to load the JSON values into the page.  I included that in the question...

Comment: Are you missing the basic concept of templates where you can pass data into the template when it is being rendered? If not, then please paste some Python that might be causing you problems.

Comment: I use a template to render the page.  If I pass data to it, it will need to go into `tal:content` or `tal:replace`.  But I want to make AJAX calls once the page is loaded, so I am using distal to load JSON values into the page.  Distal requires a Javascript call after the page has loaded, so as far as I can tell I need to load the page , request the JSON values and then pass them to distal to be loaded into the page.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You implied that the AJAX request was not ideal because it caused a stutter in the loading and that you wanted to load some arbitrary JSON values when you initially render the page. My question was, why are you not just passing the values to the template when it is rendered, instead of doing an AJAX call when the page is loaded? I don't claim to know anything about distal, but this question didn't seem to be related to javascript.

Comment: "My question was, why are you not just passing the values to the template when it is rendered": this is my question... 

What is the best way to do this?  I get rendering a template with data, but if I want to use JSON later for AJAX calls, is there some way to combine the two?

Answer (score 3):

You can share the same data between a couple views. If the request is via AJAX you would return a json-encoded version of the data (`some_data_route`). If you also want to render this data when rendering the initial html page then just pass it into your template and deal with it there.

```py
@view_config(route_name='some_data_route', renderer='json')
def data_view(request):
    data = load_data(request) # find the data somewhere
    return {'data': data}

@view_config(route_name='some_route', renderer='some_route.html.mako')
def view(request):
    data = load_data(request)
    return {'data': data}
```

Now, you can do some tricks to make the rendering code in your template more similar to the ajax handling code if you wish. For example maybe you want to JSON-encode `data` and then in your chameleon template you can just pass that data into your AJAX callback. This wouldn't be invoked until the javascript is loaded, but at least it wouldn't require the initial HTTP request.

In Pyramid 1.4 there is a cool trick to embed some html rendering in a mako `def` which you can invoke from Python directly. This lets you use the same HTML snippet as an AJAX response or directly in your template. I think this feature also exists for chameleon but I am not certain.